# Encryption at Rest, MongoDB, Azure Key vault - unable to connect to your azure vault account

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-keyvault, mongodb-atlas

Firstly, I am trying to connect my Azure Key Vault to my Encryption at Rest using your Key Management. I followed the guide on MongoDB documentation [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzvCw.png)https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-azure-kms/

[image from MongoDB Atlas Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzvCw.png)

What I've done so far which havn't worked.

I have set up the application and added the client secret, the application has the role "Azure key Vault Reader" assigned to it through the subscription.

I have setup the Key vault under the same subscription as above - with its own resource group to match it. And generated the key.
The key has all the operations.

So I have the Application with Vault Key Reader access and the Key Vault containing the key.

Client(Application) ID is filled with info from the application.

Tenant ID is filled with tenant ID from the application.

Secret is created and stored in the application -  is added. (Not the ID)

Subscription ID copied from key vault is added.

Resource group name copied from key vault is added.

Key Vault Name copied from key vault is added.

lastly the Key Identifier is copied from the vault and added.

Still I get this error - is there something wrong with the way I went about it?
I feel I have tried everything combination of setup but it seems like the credentials are setup in a wrong way which I do not understand since it was all copied directly from Azure.

"We were unable to connect to your Azure Key Vault account. Please check your credentials and try again."

Comment: Enable Azure Key Vault logging and check the status code.  That will tell you if your creds are bad, you have an access policy issue, or if you're not reaching the Key Vault at all.

Comment: Did you configure these access policies in your key vault : 

Key Management Operations

GET
LIST
Cryptographic Operations

ENCRYPT
DECRYPT for the app registration (service principal)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions with the logs, the problem was the RBAC. The Azure key Vault Reader role wasn't enough, and shouldn't have been under the resource group. Giving the application a higher vault role and setting it under the subscription worked. Thanks

Comment: How do you give your application role.

Answer (score 0):

> "We were unable to connect to your Azure Key Vault account. Please
> check your credentials and try again."

As per @Matt Small suggestion in the comment section, if we enable Azure Key Vault logging, we can check if the issue is with wrong credentials or with access policy or network related issue.

If the issue is with access, we can provide the Key Vault Contributor role or add an access policy to get, list permissions for Keys and Secrets for the service principal (App Registration)

As per @Hurup comment, Azure Key Vault Reader role was not enough and the role should not be under Resource Group. Giving the Application higher vault role and setting it under the subscription can resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. In the end I figured out that I did not have to create the role assignment 'Have an Active Directory Application with the role of Azure key Vault Reader assigned to it.' on the active directory app, but on the Key Vault.

I followed the manual from MongoDb and then in a final step did;

1. Go to Key Vault
2. Select key vault
3. Select Access Control (IAM)
4. Select Grant access to this resource
5. Select role Key Vault Reader
6. Assign access to :User, group, or service principal
7. +Select Members
8. Type Application name
9. Review and assign...

After this I could save the settings on MongoDB to use encryption at rest.

Comment: When I get to step 8, I only see Users, not the Application Name. Is it something to do with 'service principal' ?

Comment: I figured it out, the autosuggest in the portal wasn't intuitive. 
I just had to explicitly type the letters of my registered app